# Replace part of string in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got thousand of strings that contains data and with id's that is marked with a '@xx'. If the string has a '|' it menas that there is more data with an ID.

How do I find and replace all ID's that contains a specific ID? If I want to change  @1 to @24 I don't want @11 to be changed to @241

Some exampels *with expected output*:

```
21600-39600@1 -> 21600-39600@24 
21600-39600@2 -> 21600-39600@2
21600-39600@7|39600-52200@11|68000-72200@1 -> 21600-39600@7|39600-52200@11|68000-72200@24
```

Replace(column, '@1', '@24') will not work because @11 will be changed to @241. So I need to know if it is the end of the string or if it ends with an '|'

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: I did edit it with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick and dirty** but you could just do something like:

```
-- Update the end bits
UPDATE table
SET field = LEFT('field', LEN('field') -2) + '@24'
WHERE field LIKE '%@1';

-- Update the in between bits
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(field, '@1|', '@24|')
WHERE field LIKE '%@1|%'; -- This where statement is optional due to the nature of the REPLACE.
```

Otherwise you'll have to look into the magical world of REGEX. If this is something you'd want to run more than once, I'd surely look into that. If this is just a one-time-fix-thingy, meh. It's thursday, I'd call it a valid excuse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @t table(col varchar(100))
insert into @t 
select '21600-39600@1' union all
select '21600-39600@2' union all
select '21600-39600@7|39600-52200@11|68000-72200@1'


select col,case when new_col like '%|' then 
               substring(new_col,1,len(new_col)-1) 
            else 
                 new_col end as new_col 
from
(
select col,
case when col+'|' like '%@1|%' then 
Replace(col+'|', '@1|', '@24|') else col end as new_col 
from @t
) as t
```

Result

```
col                                            new_col
---------------------------------------------  ------------
21600-39600@1                                 21600-39600@24
21600-39600@2                                 21600-39600@2
21600-39600@7|39600-52200@11|68000-72200@1    21600-39600@7|39600-52200@11|68000-72200@24
```

Comment: What about the strings with multiple `|` delimited sections, each with their own `@xx` value? Or was that edit added after you answered?

Comment: What happens when one of the middle ones contains `@1|` ? Wouldn't that result in stripping the `|` in the middle as well?

Comment: People get too focussed on writing everything in a single query these days, while spliting stuff like this up enhances readability massively.

Comment: Yes I agree. But I do not think you need UPDATE in this case as you need to keep on updating the data when new data are added. So better way is to create a view with just SELECT